# OpenMP not seeing all the CPUs

Tags: c, windows, mingw, openmp, libgomp

I use OpenMP with MinGW on Windows. GCC version 7.2.0 x86-64-posix-sev-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project.
On a computer with 2 x Xeon E5-2699 V4 running Windows Server 2016. I am running:

```
printf("%d ", omp_get_num_procs());
printf("%d ", omp_get_max_threads());
printf("%d ", omp_get_thread_limit());
printf("%d ", omp_get_proc_bind());
```

which produces:

```
44, 44, 2147483647, 0
```

There are 44 physical cores total with hyperthreading. OpenMP doesn't see one of the CPUs at all.

EDIT:
After confirming the same code works correctly with CLang and looking into source of libgomp I discovered it's related to implementation of libgomp. They use old way to count processors on Windows (iterating over output of GetProcessAffinityMask which only works if there are less than 64 logical cores on the system)